# Reactjs error, objects are not valid as react child?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using reactjs in front end and nodejs as backend. I'm calling my backend (localhost:3001/api/tunes) through this code :

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch("/api/itunes")
    .then((results)=>{
        this.setState({queryResult:results});
    })
}
```

This code is supposed to return a single string value which I'm assigning to local state variable queryResult. I can't understand why the code gives error - objects are not valid react child.

My render function :

```
render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" 
                        value={this.state.queryValue} onChange={this.handleQueryChange} />
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"
                        onClick={this.submitQuery}></button>
                    </form>

                    <div>{this.state.queryResult}</div>
                </div>

        );
}
```

this is what I'm getting from my server:

```
router.get('/api/itunes',(req,res,next)=>{
    request('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson', 
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
        var result =JSON.parse(body);
        res.send(result.results[0].artistName);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: please show the  render method

Comment: You can't just render the response from the API. You'll have to map it to individual elements.

Comment: You are trying to render `<div>{this.state.queryResult}</div>` and hence you get this error, you need to map over your response and render it

Comment: even though the result is string, then also i can't just assign to local state variable ?

Comment: @ASHUTOSHCHANDRA It's not a string, judging by the error message.

Comment: can you show the response too. Judging by the error its not a string, and even if it is, its parseable to a JSON object

Comment: i added the response code

Comment: Then another problem could be the way you are initialising state, can you make sure its is `state = { queryResult: ''}` and not `state = { queryResult: {}}`

Comment: yes , state = {queryResult :""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to render whole object which is `this.state.queryResult` .

React cannot render objects.You must convert this to String or have to extract each value from the object.

You can easily check this using `{console.log(this.state.queryResult)}`

Comment: can you suggest how to do it properly, returned value from the api is a string.

Comment: {JSON.stringify(this.state.queryResult)}

But it is not the appropriate method  you have to extract each attribute from the object and print